# Export multiline SQL in Jupyter

Tags: python, sql, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to assign to a python variable in Jupyter a multiline SQL query in order to export it

I have only been able to do this for a single line of SQL like this

```
daystests= %sql SELECT * FROM users
daystests.csv('file.csv')
```

However I want to be able to organize my query in multiple lines and assign this multiline query to a python variable that I can later export

Answer (score 1):

You may use the triple quotes for multi-line strings in python

```
daystests= """
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
  users
"""
daystests.csv('file.csv')
```